# Adding dependencies to my project when my AAR already contains them

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aar

Why does gradle force me to add dependencies to my main module when my AAR library already uses those dependencies?

Example:

**My AAR library gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.android.support:design:22.2.1')
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1')
    compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1')
    compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1')
    compile('de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0')
}
```

**My app gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.firetrap.blaap"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile ('my_package_name:channels.base@aar')
 }
```

Why can't I use, for example, `com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1` from my AAR?

Comment: Are you using the aar in the libs folder or with a maven repo?

Comment: i've tried in both, i've a personal maven repo and uploaded the aar and use it and the result it's the same

Comment: The aar file doesn't contain the dependencies, then you have to add all the dependencies in the main module if you are using a local aar file. For the maven repo, check the pom file

Answer (score 0):

This is because your class files wont be taken into the dex of your aar. But I think you seeking for a solution not an answer to your question. A solution could be to extract and download the aar and include it in your library I think that'll work.